# Can websites detect use of simple Tampermonkey scripts?

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey, userscripts

Out of curiosity and not being able to find a clear answer, I was wondering. Are websites able to detect use of Tampermonkey user-scripts? If so, is it any script or only if it has specific functionalities?
Would a simple script like the following be detectable by a website?

```
(function() {
  var randomizer = Math.floor(Math.random() * 241) + 20; //Gets a random number between 0 and 240, then adds 20
  //console.log(randomizer);
  setTimeout(function(){ location.reload(); }, randomizer*1000); 
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr - no**

The browser, nor the Tampermonkey plugin do not advertise the presence of userscripts. That is there isn't a straightforward way to just write `if(tampermonkeyActive)` and detect it.

However, webpage may implement anti-tampering techniques. These may not be directed at Tampermonkey, but any type of suspicious behaviour. This may include:

- Suspicious amount of activity per unit of time per user
- Activity when the webpage is not in focus
- Unexpected global variables or function calls
- Checking `isTrusted` on events.

Of all these, I have only experienced the first example, that is logging activity server-side and manually reviewing it. Thus if you're trying to automate something and the site owner is not keen on it, you should consider making it look human-like.

#### Security

Tampermonkey script already runs in wrapped scope, so the self-invoking function is redundant.

Detecting a userscript can be something a malicious actor might want to do. If you use `@grant` to get any of the special features of tampermonkey, and also use `@grant unsafeWindow`, leaking any of the functions could allow actor that detects that to hack your browser. It would take a lot of effort though - they need to detect the userscript, then manually hack it, since every userscript is different.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am not sure how keen they are on refreshing it automatically with a script such as this, but as their website does not update itself properly I see it necessary. Wanted to make sure there is no "proof" of it not being a human pressing the F5 key or clicking the refresh icon at random intervals, so your response answers my question. Thanks!